# Block Elements Not Vertically Aligning

Tags: html, block, element

I'm currently trying to develop a website. At the moment I'm trying to get the design down, but its giving me quite a tough time.

I have 5 div's. Each one contains two span's, column1 and column2. The div's are block and the span's are inline-block. However, for some reason the div's don't want to align vertically. Any help is appreciated. Also, another thing. Some of the span's inside the div's were replaced with div's. I did this because I planned on using block elements inside of those particular areas and to do that and still validate they had to be div's, not span's.

Below is my current code:

```css
.header {
    color: #AEC6CF;
    font-family: gabriola;
 font-weight: 900;
 font-size: 50px;
 position: relative;
}


/* ID */

#row1 {
    width: 98%;
    height: 15%;
 position: absolute;
 display: block;
}

#row2 {
    width: 98%;
    height: 2.5%;
 position: absolute;
 display: block;
}

#row3 {
    width: 98%;
    height: 70%;
 position: absolute;
 display: block;
}

#row4 {
    width: 98%;
    height: 2.5%;
 position: absolute;
 display: block;
}

#row5 {
    width: 98%;
    height: 7.25%;
 position: absolute;
 display: block;
}

#column1 {
 border-bottom: 3px solid black;
 border-right: 3px solid black;
 width: 20%;
 height: 100%;
 left: 0;
 position: absolute;
 display: inline-block;
}

#column2 {
 border-bottom: 3px solid black;
 border-left: 3px solid black;
 width: 79.8%;
 height: 100%;
 right: 0;
 position: absolute;
 display: inline-block;
}


/* Misc. */

.center {
    text-align: center;
}

.right {
    text-align: right;
}

.left {
    text-align: left;
}

.clearfix  {
 float: clear;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <head>
  <meta charset=utf-8>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">
  <title>Design</title>
 </head>

 <body>
  <div id="row1">
   <div id="column1" class="clearfix">
   </div>
            
            <div id="column2" class="clearfix">
             <h1 class="header center">Generic Header</h1>
            </div>
  </div>

  <div id="row2">
   <div id="column1" class="clearfix">
   </div>

   <div id="column2" class="clearfix">
   </div>
  </div>

  <div id="row3">
   <span id="column1" class="clearfix">
   </span>

   <span id="column2" class="clearfix">
   </span>
  </div>

  <div id="row4">
   <span id="column1" class="clearfix">
   </span>

   <span id="column2" class="clearfix">
   </span>
  </div>

  <div id="row5">
   <div id="column1" class="clearfix" style="border-bottom: 0px;">
   </div>

   <div id="column2" class="clearfix" style="border-bottom: 0px;">
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your HTML and CSS are very confused. First, a `span` isn't for layout struct, only use `div`s and similars. I don't understand why you put `display: block;` in the divs, since they already have this value by default. And there aren't reasons to some elements have `position: absolute`. Everything is confused, I can't understand what you are trying to do. Some images would be helpful.

Comment: Yes, I understand now that I was using some things incorrectly. However, I used the code from the poster below and fixed it. Now, they won't retain their height and width. If you would like an image I may be able to provide one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of issues... is there a reason why all of your divs are positioned absolutely? Without specific margins they all just stack ontop of each other since `position: absolute;` takes them out of the flow of the document. Even relative to the container, they will all be stacked inside of the container.

Secondly, your column widths add up to over 100%. You need to account for the space that the border takes up.

Here is your code without absolutely positioned divs and with adjusted column widths. Hopefully that should get you on the right track.

```css
.header {
    color: #AEC6CF;
    font-family: gabriola;
 font-weight: 900;
 font-size: 50px;
 position: relative;
}


/* ID */

#row1 {
    width: 98%;
    height: 15%;
 display: block;
}

#row2 {
    width: 98%;
    height: 2.5%;
 display: block;
}

#row3 {
    width: 98%;
    height: 70%;
 display: block;
}

#row4 {
    width: 98%;
    height: 2.5%;
 display: block;
}

#row5 {
    width: 98%;
    height: 7.25%;
 display: block;
}

#column1 {
 border-bottom: 3px solid black;
 border-right: 3px solid black;
 width: 20%;
 height: 100%;
 left: 0;
 display: inline-block;
}

#column2 {
 border-bottom: 3px solid black;
 border-left: 3px solid black;
 width: 73%;
 height: 100%;
 right: 0;
 display: inline-block;
}


/* Misc. */

.center {
    text-align: center;
}

.right {
    text-align: right;
}

.left {
    text-align: left;
}

.clearfix  {
 float: clear;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <head>
  <meta charset=utf-8>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">
  <title>Design</title>
 </head>

 <body>
  <div id="row1">
   <div id="column1" class="clearfix">
   </div>
            
            <div id="column2" class="clearfix">
             <h1 class="header center">Generic Header</h1>
            </div>
  </div>

  <div id="row2">
   <div id="column1" class="clearfix">
   </div>

   <div id="column2" class="clearfix">
   </div>
  </div>

  <div id="row3">
   <span id="column1" class="clearfix">
   </span>

   <span id="column2" class="clearfix">
   </span>
  </div>

  <div id="row4">
   <span id="column1" class="clearfix">
   </span>

   <span id="column2" class="clearfix">
   </span>
  </div>

  <div id="row5">
   <div id="column1" class="clearfix" style="border-bottom: 0px;">
   </div>

   <div id="column2" class="clearfix" style="border-bottom: 0px;">
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you. Now they are stacking on top of each other vertically. However, they aren't holding their dimensions (height and width) like before. Any idea as to why and if so how to fix it?

Comment: @MainStream Can you be a little more specific? I'm not sure what you mean. What should the widths and heights be?

Comment: Now that I look back at the question, I can see that I didn't do a very good job explaining my current predicament. So I'll use pictures to speak for me. If you still fail to see my problem let me know. The thing is it happens in every Div/Row/Column.

Comment: Layout Before Text:
http://i.stack.imgur.com/wj0C2.png

Layout After Text:
http://i.stack.imgur.com/P4tjd.png

Comment: Edit: I fixed it but I had to float column2 right. :/